# Creating Runnable Jar with external files included

Tags: java, file, jar, executable-jar

I want to build a runnable jar in java. I need to include some of the  files in the jar so that when I execute jar the files are automatically read from the java class. Hence I created a folder in the project and referred these files from the project. I created jar file following some tutorial but I could not able to include these external files in my jar file. Please let me about creating runnable jar with external files.

My file struture is

```
Test
|
|
-------src
|        |
|        default package
|                      |
|                      |
|                      test1.java
|
 -------FileFOlder
|              |
|              | 
|              abc.txt
```

I am accessing **abc.txt** in **test1.java** class. 
My code is,

```
public class test1 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    char [] read = new char[20];
    String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
    path = path+"\\Newfolder\\abc.txt";
    System.out.println(path);
    File nF = new File(path);
    FileReader fR = new FileReader(nF);
    fR.read(read);
    for(char c : read){
        System.out.print(c);
    }
    fR.close();
    System.out.println(" Hi..This is test program ");
}

}
```

When I create executable jar using eclipse export option, I am unable to see FileFolder directory inside the jar. Please give me some information regarding this.

Comment: Define 'not able to include these external files in my jar file'. Why not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what you should do instead:

Put that file back *in* your jar file.  Use `class.getResourceAsStream()` to read it instead of `File` and `FileReader`.  Here is an explanation of how to do that: [How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please let me know how can I put my text files inside the jar file.

Comment: @Anup what have you tried?  How are you building your jar file now?

Comment: I am building jar files through Eclipse. I select Export option and then runnable Jar and finally selects the class. I did not get any options to select other folder.

Comment: I think this will explain how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7284648/61624

Comment: do you have library handling options? selecting `Extract libraries into generate JAR` might help.

Comment: @ScottScooterWeidenkopf - Thank you for your response. Yes I tried with that option and all other option. But there was same outcome. The jar file doesnot have file in it.

Comment: hmmm I actually have a JAR that *should* file in it right now...how do I even check if the JAR actually contains the file?

Comment: How about modified external files? Your method assumes the files are read only, in a lot of cases you need to change the contents of text file after you create the Jar.

Answer (score 14):

Problem Solved!

here is how:

1) right click your project folder and create a new folder.

2) move all of your files that you want packed into the jar into that folder.

3) click `project -> properties -> Build Path -> Source -> Add Folder` and select that folder you just created.

4) create your JAR!

Since you already have created your folder with abc.txt insideit, you can skip steps 1 and 2

EDIT: one way you can make sure your JAR contains these files is to use 7zip.

Comment: Thank you very much. I created jar file as you specified and I got the text file in the jar file. But now I am unable to find out a way to access that file from my code. So when I run my jar file I am getting FileNotFound exception. I am unable to use that file and read the content. Please let me know if you anything about this.

Comment: I have never done this myself, but after a little browsing I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593154/get-a-resource-using-getresource) stackoverflow question. it seems that you can user `ClassLoader` to access files on your classpath, which would include your abc.txt

Comment: oooh i think i may have found the [`answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Comment: Thank you for your link.. I used getResourceAsStream() method. I used the link to refer and there was one more link which I found was very clear and useful. [link] (http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/read-text-file-from-jar-file)..I used this link and solved the proble. But I appreciate your help.. Thank you very much..

Comment: @Anup   Hey, the link you have specific is broken.