# JAVA: including files in jar and how to access them

Tags: java, file, jar, resources

I need to include some image files in the exported jar file, I searched a bit and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092011) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464366) answers but I can't get it to work.

so my file structure is:

```
root
-assets
--clean.png
-src
...
```

I added the assets folder to the build path as suggested but if I unzip the jar the files are not in the assets folder but in the root.

I tried the following codes:

```
InputStream i = getClass().getResourceAsStream("assets/clean.png");
InputStream i = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/clean.png");
InputStream i = getClass().getResourceAsStream("clean.png");
InputStream i = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/clean.png");
```

but they none of them work, `i` is `null`. What I'm missing?

I'm using Maven

Comment: Do you use Maven ? Did you unzip your JAR to check if your resources were actually included ?

Comment: yes I use Maven, I updated the question

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html. Your resources must be in src/main/resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your files into Maven resource directory `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` for tests.

Documentation : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/