# Create Java exe with external files

Tags: java

I have a `jar` file with external files (i.e. **executables**) that I access using Runtime.

I was wondering if I would be able to package these files into a *single executable* (not necessarily a jar) where I can still access all of the files using the windows file system.

Comment: You definitely can. You can even package a JRE with the exe so your clients don't need to install the JRE.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions how to actually do it?

Comment: I used Launch4j, but there's lots of options out there.

Comment: @ScubaSteve Do you know how to get the file path of resources inside the .exe?

Comment: It's been a while since I had to do this. The java classes should work just fine.

Assets should be packaged separately.

Comment: Worth noting that if you're packaging for a client source that you own, you'll want to use an obfuscation process. Otherwise they can get your java code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can combine these 2 solutions to get your answer.

[Creating Runnable Jar with external files included](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18091046/4374291)

[How can I convert a .jar to an .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4330936/4374291)

I don't know if two answers will make this one duplicate?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'd looked at the first link but the get resource as stream approach doesn't work because I need to get the file path for the runtime and the number of files means that copying the files out of the jar seems inefficient