# Exporting Java Program As JAR With Other Files In Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I am trying to export a project in Eclipse and it references text files stored in the src folder. When I export it to a JAR file it doesnt seem to include those text files. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091046/creating-runnable-jar-with-external-files-included/18092011

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a resource file from within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar)