# How to get a package file path in a java project even after exporting and running from different file location

Tags: java

[image]

From this image, when i run this class as Java application, it works perfectly fine.

I have created a executable jar file and saved in Downloads folder and when i run the jar, i am getting `"java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/uanem/Downloads/testng.xml (No such file or directory)"`

How to get my project's folder path and refer this testng.xml irrespective from where i am running jar file?

Comment: Please follow the [contribution guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a good question. Please do not post images of your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a relative path in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209085/how-to-define-a-relative-path-in-java)

Comment: @flaxel I have posted the image because anybody can understand the my file or folder structure.

Comment: Pardon me if I am stating the obvious, but have you checked whether the JAR file you created contains file `testing.xml`? And if it does, is it in the path that appears in the error message?

Comment: I guess that the xml file is not exported with the jar. So you can copy the file to your specific location and use a realtive path or you can put it in the jar and maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar/) can help you. The method `getResource` could be helpful.

Comment: @flaxel I am wondering i have extracted the jar and couldnt find my .xml file. May i know why it is not included?

Comment: It is not part of the build path. But you can add a [source folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091046/creating-runnable-jar-with-external-files-included/) to add the xml file.

Comment: @flaxel i have created and moved the file under '/src/test/java/testng/' and created a SelAutomation.jar file. Now the xml file exists, but getting the same error 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/uanem/Downloads/src/test/java/testng/testng.xml (No such file or directory)'

Comment: Normally the test folder is not packed. Otherwise you can get the file with the [getResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593154/get-a-resource-using-getresource) method.

Comment: @flaxel Could you please help how can i use getResource and get the file path and use here? Tried moving the file to src/main/resources, but didnt help.

Comment: Getting filenotfound when i use like this   URL res = TestNGRunner.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/src/main/resources/testng/testng.xml");
  File file = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
  String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43415602/10951752) you can use the method like this: `File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("testing.xml").getFile());`.

Comment: ***Never*** call the `getFile()` method of URL, ever.  The proper way to read a resource is by using `getResourceAsStream` or by using the `openStream` method of the URL returned by getResource.  A resource will not be a separate file when it’s part of a .jar file, and the getFile() method does not return a valid filename, it just returns a portion of a URL with all percent-escapes intact.

Answer (score 0):

An executable jar has no memory of where you built it from, so there is no easy way to go back to the testng.xml file (why do you even need it?)

In the following I assume testng can look for this file in the classpath.  (If you are unsure what that means, consider learning it - this is a very frequent problem for new programmers).

You can do one or more of the following:

- Explicitly tell the path to the file on the command line.  The exact syntax depends on the discovery mechanism used by testng.  You may have to hand carry it from the args-string to the invocation point.
- Add the Downloads folder to the class-path encoded in the executable jar manifest.  That will not be portable to other systems, but may be enough for your personal use.
- Move the file inside the classpath (src/java/resources) so it is included in your executable jar, and testng can locate it there.
- Consider why this is needed in your executable jar, and if possible remove that functionality.  Then the problem goes away.
- Place it next to the executable jar and ask the JVM where the code is running.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/227640/53897